# How to close current Browser window and redirect to a previously opened window for the same browser

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have two asp page,first one is home and second one is test. In home page user can select the type of test they want to take up, and after pressing start button a new window is open for taking the test. What i want to achieve is , after completing the test i want to close the test window and redirect to another page, and this redirect should hit the previously opened home window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't clarify that you have popup window or blank window i am aspecting for the popup 
In submit click button press

```
String x = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.opener.location.href='**Your new url of new page after completing test**';self.close();</script>";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page,this.Page.GetType(), "script", x,false);
```

From **self close** you will be able to close current window and by **window.opener.location.href** you will able to redirect to new url
I hope this will help you

regards....:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do these 2 ways:

1. Window.Open() /.showmodalDialog() and keep parent and child open as well, or
2. On the home page click on  your start button. Use code `Response.Redirect("~/Test.aspx");` assuming it resides with `Home.aspx`. Take your test using `ASp.Net wizard control` or `hiddens divs` what ever suits you easy. Manipulate data on test page , save and get result to and from database using SqlConnection and SqlCommand assuming you have `Sql Server` as backend. Hold the table or any value in either cache or Session and throw it on your home page. Do whatever you want.

Comment: hi,i'm a newbie in all this things. Can you please elaborate the first option, thnx for your quick reply

Answer (score -2):

This will be not possible. What you can do is to redirect the user to the home page after completing the test, but this will be in the same windows.

Comment: It's entirely possible

Comment: The above solutions are wrong and do not resolve the problem. The ieda is to return the user on previous opened Window, not to send him on the same URL!