# Redirect Parent - Close Popup - ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need help in redirecting parent page from clicking a submit button in its popup window

Should happen:

1. User hits submit button, parameters from popup will be passed in a url
2. Parent page will redirect to Details page
3. popup window closed

What happens:

1. User hits submit button, parameters from popup will be passed in a url
2. Entries submitted
3. Parent does not redirect
4. popup window gets redirected instead

CODE

```
ReturnValue.url = "TransDetailMain.aspx?AcctDate=" +AcctDate+ "&AcctCategoryCode=" +AcctCategoryCode+ "&DeptProfitCtr=" +DeptProfitCtr+ "&RefDocNum=" + RefDocNum + "&COMMAND=Edit&REFERRING_PAGE_KEY=MtMonthlyCatalystMain.aspx";//?AcctDate="+AcctDate;
//window.returnValue = ReturnValue;
window.location.href = ReturnValue.url;
// window.opener.location.href = ReturnValue.url;
//window.parent.location.href=ReturnValue.url;
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
// window.location.replace(ReturnValue.url);
```

ISSUES:

1. Code used to work in windows 2003 server
2. migrated to 2008 and it's not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using javascript so i am writing here

check my answer here
[How to close current Browser window and redirect to a previously opened window for the same browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196900/how-to-close-current-browser-window-and-redirect-to-a-previously-opened-window-f/19197132#19197132)

```
String x = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.opener.location.href='**Your new url of new page after completing test**';self.close();</script>";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page,this.Page.GetType(), "script", x,false);
```

It illustates that self.close() current will be closed and new url will be open
so your new code will be looks like this

so now what

```
String x = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.opener.location.href='**TransDetailMain.aspx?AcctDate=" +AcctDate+ "&AcctCategoryCode=" +AcctCategoryCode+ "&DeptProfitCtr=" +DeptProfitCtr+ "&RefDocNum=" + RefDocNum + "&COMMAND=Edit&REFERRING_PAGE_KEY=MtMonthlyCatalystMain.aspx**';self.close();</script>";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page,this.Page.GetType(), "script", x,false);
```

Put this one in your pop up submit click
So what will be happen is parent will be redirected and current window will be closed
Note:this code is not tested
I hope this will help you regards...:)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It opens the "Details" page in the popup, but the parent window still remains open, even if it passed by thru the self.close();